# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto en Gridview asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb

Este es mi código en asp, tengo este elemento en un gridwiev y deseo mostrar imágenes que tengo en mi base de datos

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image id="ImageId" runat="server" CssClass="imgProduct" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

En el evento rowdatabound lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
Dim objImg As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image
objImg = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ImageId"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)

Dim bytes As Byte() = CType(Conect.executeScalar(" SELECT imagen FROM imagenes WHERE idImagen = '671b20bd-cecc-445e-8442-393c1f2327a4' "), Byte())

Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

If objImg Is Nothing Then

    objImg.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:image/png;base64,") & base64String

End If
```

Me manda la siguiente excepcion:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
>   Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
>
> ```
> Error de código fuente: 
> Línea 240:                If objImg Is Nothing Then
> Línea 241:
> Línea 242:                    objImg.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString("data:image/png;base64,") & base64String
> Línea 243:
> Línea 244:                End If
> ```

Cabe resaltar, que este procedimiento lo realizo de la misma manera en una pagina aspx para mostrar una sola imagen y ahí no tengo ningún problema, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: `If objImg Is Nothing` verifica que `objImg` este null, por lo que si la condicion se da, cuando intentes acceder a `objImg.ImageUrl` te lanzara null.

Comment: objImg = TryCast(row.FindControl("ImageId"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)  Lo resolvi de esa manera, tenias razon el objeto image me estaba dando null, pero con esa linea ya tengo el objeto y puedo modificar su propiedad, gracias